# JHipster - Angular Universal integration example (issues and thoughts)

Tags: angular, jhipster, server-side-rendering

I have integrated a JHipster project with Angular Universal. You may find it [here](https://github.com/brydko/jhipster-universal) along with an explanation. I'd say it works pretty well for a simple project. It is also not hard to integrate (it's mostly configuration). After tinkering with it for a while I think it may lay a foundation for a JHipster blueprint. However, I would like to express some doubts first.

[image: JHipster Universal overview]

**Doubts / thoughts:**

- Even if the project works I still think that something is missing. What about security ? Dynamic routes ? Launching express instance properly ? Securing express instance ? Lack of backend integration ?

Please share your thoughts.

**Recent updates**

- Solved previous issues
- Upgraded to JHipster 6.10.0
- Added SSR build to 'prod' profile

**Future updates**

- Hybrid SSR
- Starting bash script creation

**P.D.**

As soon as I gain some additional knowledge regarding Angular Universal I'll release a more complete version. Few reasons for not doing it right now are:

- lack of current [documentation](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1732)
- i18n [issues](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1454)

**Edit reasons**

- Solved issues
- Add updates
- Rephrasing

Comment: Cool! I hope you figure out these issues and get it working. 